# Repeat state on mouse click QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Within the code I have a `State`, a `Transition` and a `RotationAnimation` defined.

After the property change takes place, i.e. after the `rotation` is set to `360`, the `onClicked` handler is rendered mute and the animation will never be played again after subsequent `MouseArea` clicks.

Here is my current code:

```
Image{
    id: logo
    x: 29
    source: "LSFO-IngeniiSymbol.png"
    width: 70
    height: 70
    states: State {
        name: "rotated" ; when: area.pressed
        PropertyChanges {target: logo; rotation: 360 }

    }

    transitions: Transition {
        RotationAnimation { 
            id: rotateanimate
            duration: 1000
            direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent 
        onClicked: {
            logo.state = "rotated"
           // pageloader.source = "HelpDoc.qml"
           // pageloader.source = ""
           // pageloader.source = "HelpDoc.qml"
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`State`s are a way to represent different property configurations for a given `Item`. Each `State` has its unique set of values for the properties defined inside the specific `Item`.

`Transition`s are a way to add animations to an `Item` when the current `State` *changes* to another `State`. They can be applied in a "restricted way", i.e. only when the `Item` changes from a particular `State` to another (see [`from`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html#from-prop) and [`to`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html#to-prop) properties), or they can be applied "globally" for each `State` change. In any case a change is *needed*.

In your code the `state` is set to `rotated` and after that the very same `State` is reassigned so that no further changes occur. Hence, there is no room for another `Transition`, either to `rotated` `state` or the default empty-named `State`.

Anyhow, there are various ways to apply animations including, but not limited to,  [`Behavior`s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html), `Transition`s, [using predefined targets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#using-predefined-targets-and-properties) and [direct property animation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#direct-property-animation). It seems to me the latter is the way to go for this specific case. Here is a revisited version of your code with the animation triggered on mouse click:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    visible: true

    Image{
        id: logo
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-YiF6y9OXDQ8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/oFNmJLmzqDA/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
        width: 100
        height: 100

        RotationAnimation {
            id: rotate
            target:logo
            property: "rotation"
            from: 0
            to: 360
            duration: 1000
            direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
        }


        MouseArea {
            id: area
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                rotate.start()   // animation plays here!
                // your code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You solved my issue, thanks. I was going from QT's own examples so it led me a little astray. Thankyou for the knowledge